# KeyError for Column When Trying to Subset

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to subset my data by the value of a column using the typical pandas protocol:

```
df[df[column_name] == "value"]
```

But I keep getting a keyerror for "Product (ACQ Search) - ONC". I also found that checking the column names with pd.columns shows only the 4 columns I renamed at a different point in the script. Why do I keep getting a keyerror?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Load the excel file into a dataframe
df = pd.read_excel("Marginal CPA data - NOV.xlsx")

# Delete the bottom row
df = df[:-1]

# Filter the column labeled "Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC" to keep only rows with value "NonBrand"
df = df[df["Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC"] == "NonBrand"]

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Day"], format="%d %b %Y")
df = df.drop("Day", axis=1)

# Make a pivot table
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=["Media Cost", "CAFE Approvals"],
                              index=["Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC", "Product (ACQ Search) - ONC", "Date"],
                              columns=["CDJ"], aggfunc="sum")

df_pivot = pivot_table.fillna(value=0)

# Reset the column index to a single level
df_pivot.columns = ["_".join(col) for col in df_pivot.columns]

cols = {
    "Media Cost_CPA": "CPA Spend",
    "Media Cost_Non CPA (CDJ)": "CDJ Spend",
    "CAFE Approvals_CPA": "CPA Approvals",
    "CAFE Approvals_Non CPA (CDJ)": "CDJ Approvals"
}
df_pivot = df_pivot.rename(columns=cols)

# Add two new columns for Total Spend and Total Approvals
df_pivot["Total Approvals"] = df_pivot["CPA Approvals"] + df_pivot["CDJ Approvals"]
df_pivot["Total Spend"] = df_pivot["CPA Spend"] + df_pivot["CDJ Spend"]

#Remove data for days where spend is zero
df_pivot = df_pivot[df_pivot["CPA Spend"] != 0]
df_pivot = df_pivot[df_pivot["Total Approvals"] != 0]

#Sort Date and Product
df_pivot = df_pivot.sort_values("Date", ascending=True)
df_pivot = df_pivot.sort_values("Product (ACQ Search) - ONC", ascending=True)

df_pivot.to_excel("Marginal CPA data - NOV (processed).xlsx")

# filter the data to only include rows where "Product (ACQ Search) - ONC" is "Consumer"
consumer_data = df_pivot[df_pivot["Product (ACQ Search) - ONC"] == "Consumer"]
```

Data:

| Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC | Product (ACQ Search) - ONC | CDJ | Day | Media Cost | CAFE Approvals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NonBrand | Consumer | CPA | 11 Jan 2023 | 29019.77415 | 94 |
| NonBrand | Consumer | Non CPA (CDJ) | 17 Jan 2023 | 24640.36448 | 86 |
| NonBrand | Consumer | Non CPA (CDJ) | 12 Jan 2023 | 23627.78256 | 78 |
| NonBrand | Student | CPA | 17 Jan 2023 | 29863.95447 | 152 |
| NonBrand | Miles | CPA | 23 Jan 2023 | 380.94 | 1 |
| NonBrand | Miles | CPA | 07 Jan 2023 | 1786.51 | 5 |
| NonBrand | Consumer | CPA | 19 Jan 2023 | 26745.81705 | 64 |
| NonBrand | Secured | CPA | 20 Jan 2023 | 1551.35 | 19 |
| NonBrand | Consumer | Non CPA (CDJ) | 02 Feb 2023 | 41185.11225 | 66 |
| NonBrand | Student | CPA | 08 Jan 2023 | 42822.8508 | 171 |
| NonBrand | Student | CPA | 16 Jan 2023 | 29408.66012 | 160 |
| NonBrand | Consumer | CPA | 17 Jan 2023 | 29378.05227 | 85 |
| NonBrand | Miles | CPA | 10 Jan 2023 | 2019.25 | 4 |
| NonBrand | Miles | CPA | 11 Jan 2023 | 1604.98 | 4 |
| NonBrand | Secured | CPA | 21 Jan 2023 | 1704.13419 | 22 |

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to slice your data using a column that is actually an index.

You can slice your MultiIndex data frame by using `pd.IndexSlice` and passing "Consumer" to the second level:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df_pivot.loc[idx[:, "Consumer", :]]
```

Which returns the following:

|  | CPA Approvals | CDJ Approvals | CPA Spend | CDJ Spend | Total Approvals | Total Spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ('NonBrand', Timestamp('2023-01-11 00:00:00')) | 94 | 0 | 29019.8 | 0 | 94 | 29019.8 |
| ('NonBrand', Timestamp('2023-01-17 00:00:00')) | 85 | 86 | 29378.1 | 24640.4 | 171 | 54018.4 |
| ('NonBrand', Timestamp('2023-01-19 00:00:00')) | 64 | 0 | 26745.8 | 0 | 64 | 26745.8 |

See more about advanced indexing here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#

You can also reset the index and then subset the data in a manner similar to your last line:

```
df = df_pivot.reset_index()
df.loc[df["Product (ACQ Search) - ONC"] == "Consumer"]
```

Which returns the following:

|  | Campaign Type (Search ACQ) - ONC | Product (ACQ Search) - ONC | Date | CPA Approvals | CDJ Approvals | CPA Spend | CDJ Spend | Total Approvals | Total Spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NonBrand | Consumer | 2023-01-11 00:00:00 | 94 | 0 | 29019.8 | 0 | 94 | 29019.8 |
| 1 | NonBrand | Consumer | 2023-01-17 00:00:00 | 85 | 86 | 29378.1 | 24640.4 | 171 | 54018.4 |
| 2 | NonBrand | Consumer | 2023-01-19 00:00:00 | 64 | 0 | 26745.8 | 0 | 64 | 26745.8 |

The first method loses the first two indices, while the second method preserves all of the data.